# Grafana alert execution exceeded timeout, why is this happening?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I am using Grafana to set up email alerts. I have all my panels on my dashbboard created, and just turned the alerts on. However, I am now getting the following error. Alert execution exceeded the timeout. This is sending emails for all the servers on that dashboard to everyone associated with the email alert. Why is this happening? Is there too many servers on one data source? Should I change the data source from 1 to multiple?

Comment: Could you post some screenshots of your configuration?

Comment: [smtp]
enabled = true
host = localhost:25
;user =
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with trippel quotes. Ex """#password;"""
;password =
;cert_file =
;key_file =
;skip_verify = false
from_address = grafana@rbbn.com
from_name = Grafana
# EHLO identity in SMTP dialog (defaults to instance_name)
;ehlo_identity = dashboard.example.com

[emails]
;welcome_email_on_sign_up = false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is old, but still someone comes here looking for answer.
It happens when the data source you are using to generate the charts response very slowly ~ > 30s. In that case graph throws the error execution time out.